# Cambiar caracter específico en un array en JavasScript

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy aprendiendo JavaScript y tengo la siguiente pregunta: Tengo este array
de ejemplo:

```
const nombres = [ 'Cristian' , 'Jorge', 'Pablo' , 'Saulo'];
```

Cómo puedo cambiar las `'i'` por `'1'` y las `'o'` por `'0'` sin usar métodos dentro de un bucle `for`?

Lo intento, pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo.

lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```js
const nombres = ['Cristian', 'Jorge', 'Pablo', 'Saulo'];
for (let i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < nombres[i].length; j++) {
    if (nombres[i][j] === 'o') {
      nombres[i] = 'J0rge';
      console.log(nombres);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola Cristian, podrías mostrarnos lo que has intentado?

Comment: usa la funcion replace, intentalo y agrega tu duda, incluyendo tu codigo.

Comment: con un solo for para recorrer las cadenas tienes

Comment: Lo he intentado, pero no lo consigo

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar la función map para eliminar el primer bucle y replace para el segundo:

```
let resultado = nombres.map(e=> e.replace(/o/g, '0').replace(/i/g,1));
```

Comment: y hacerlo sin usar los métodos?  Lo intento de esta manera:  nombres[1][1] = 0;

Comment: @CristianAstudillo No tiene sentido hacer cosas en JavaScript sin métodos, es como pedir una limonada sin limón (que no es lo mismo que una quesadilla sin queso en la Cd. de México)

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción podría ser usar un ciclo, para después uno por uno hacer el `replace` a los elementos del arreglo:

```js
const nombres = [ 'Cristian' , 'Jorge', 'Pablo' , 'Saulo'];
var ro = /o/gi;
var ri = /i/gi;
for (let i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++){
 nombres[i] = nombres[i].replace(ro,0).replace(ri,1);
}
console.log(nombres);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, @RicardoPérez, lo intentaré; para entender, qué significa lo que está en la variable   `var ro = /o/ gi;` , el símbolo /o/?

Comment: Significa que lo que esta dentro de las diagonales /o/ es lo que se va a buscar, la g significa que va a buscar todas las coincidencias, y la i significa case sensitive osea que no le va a importar si es mayuscula o minuscula.

Comment: Muchas gracias     @RicardoPérez

Answer (score 1):

Revisa este código a ver si te sirve, solo se usa el método join para eliminar las comas y split para hacer la particion por cada una de las letras y hacer la comparacion

```js
const nombres = ['Cristian', 'Jorge', 'Pablo', 'Saulo'];
let result = null;
for (let i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++) {
  result = nombres[i].split('');
  for (let j = 0; j < nombres[i].length; j++) {
    if (result[j] == "i") {
      result[j] = "1"
    } else if (result[j] == "o") {
      result[j] = "0"
    }
  }
  nombres[i] = result.join('').toString();
}
console.log(nombres);
```

Comment: Gracias @LordOfLies, lo revisaré

Answer (score 0):

Esta es similar a [la respuesta de Pablo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/260594/65) con las siguientes diferencias

- Se usa `forEach` en lugar de `map`.
- Se hace uso de una función anónima en lugar de una función flecha como *callback*
- Se usan vectores (arrays) e índices (nombre[i])
- Se usar `item` en lugar de `e` porque si bien para un programador con ciertas experiencia es claro que `e` se es una variable a la que se asigna un elemento del vector en cada iteración, para alguien que empieza podría resultar confuso además de que es un buena práctica usar nombres descriptivos (asumo que *item* es entendido por todos como un miembro de una lista, pero si no fuera así, se puede reemplazar por *elemento*, *miembro* o algún otro término siembre y cuando este no sea una palabra reservada de JavaScript o las APIs usadas por la plataforma en la que se ejecute el código.

```js
const nombres = ['Cristian', 'Jorge', 'Pablo', 'Saulo'];
nombres.forEach(function(item,i){
  return nombres[i] = item.replace(/i/g,'1').replace(/o/g,'0');
});
console.log(nombres);
```

Sobre el código en la pregunta, se están usando for anidados y dos índices `nombres[i][j]` pero esto no tiene sentido porque el vector (Array) sólo tiene una dimensión, bastaría con un único for y `nombres[i]`.

Comment: Muchas gracias Rubén.